# Reinstalling XP on old laptop, how do I set up a PXE server on my win7 desktop?

Tags: windows-xp, pxe

I'm reinstalling XP on a very old laptop with a dead cd drive. I don't have any floppy drives and it doesn't support usb booting, so PXE is my only option.

Can I set up a PXE server on my Windows 7 Desktop? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you'll need to configure it as a DHCP server as well.  The primary piece of software you'd use is [TFTPD32](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftftpd32.jounin.net%2F&rct=j&q=tfptd%20windows&ei=d4JATdLbM4HGlQeCmoTwAg&usg=AFQjCNFt5yHHj3UhOFCVpIN51-_KBvEEnA&sig2=ayXyvAn2W7mDFMjx1jRgNw&cad=rja).  It's pretty well known for being reliable on a Windows system.

If you have another system with which you can play around, I've just configured a Debian Linux based TFTPD/PXE server that's running smoothly in my organization.  Let me know if I can help further.